# Writing algorithm functions for STL

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, iterator

I have a `std::set` which is of type `point`

```
struct point
{
  int x;
  int y;
  int z;
};
```

Suppose I want to perform three different operation on each variable in set i.e

- Find the smallest number from x variables.
- Get missing elements from y variables
  using set difference.
- Get product of all z variables.

At this point, should i use three predefined alogrithmic functions in sequence or should I write my own alogrithm which would perform all three operations by iterating over the set the once?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Even if you get a ten-fold speed increase, if that piece of code only uses 5% of your application's time, you've just decreased the execution time to 95%. So, unless you know this is a real bottleneck in your application, don't waste time trying to optimize it. And the only way to know this is through profiling.

Answer (score 2):

Start to use 3 functions in sequence. If you get performance issues try to write your own algorithm.

> Premature optimization is evil.

Comment: Also bear in mind what Knuth wrote just after the quote you paraphrased: "Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%. A good programmer will not be lulled into complacency by such reasoning, he will be wise to look carefully at the critical code; but only after that code has been identified."

Comment: Re *"Premature optimization is evil."*: It is usually rounded off to mean (used as an excuse): Never ever optimise anything.